# search_after returning results before specified element

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a match_all query sorting on @timestamp and _uid.   With the parameters set from=0 and size=25.   I get back 25 ids as expected.

If I take the same query and then add search_after id 12 with the same parameters,  I would expect to get id {12,13,14,15..25}.   Instead I get back Id {4,5,6,...25}.

I'm very confused on how this can happen?   Doesn't search_after by its very name imply it will only give back the results after the entry specified from the original query?

Also for search_after, I am using:    "search_after": [1527201104032,"log#AWOUR2VorbUl8ovcHSNq"],

Obviously the second entry is my _uid.  I have assumed the first entry is a cursor id.  Is this correct?   Regardless I am copying it exactly as-is from my first query without search_after.

Answer (score 0):

`search_after` should always match your sort so the first value is the timestamp, second is _uid.

To get docs from 12 on you'd need to provide search_after with the timestamp and _uid of 11.